# Image and video processing in mobile app

Tags: android, image-processing

Which is the best way to perform Image Processing and Video Processing in an android app?

Comment: Please stop inserting the `android` TAG in your post TITLE. It's just not the right place where to put a tag!

Comment: Any suggestion regarding my question?

Comment: read about [openCV] - [TesnsorFlow].

Answer (score 0):

Opencv is good library used for image processing. OpenCV is written in C++ and its primary interface is in C++ but there are bindings in Python and java. You can use [opencv for andorid sdk](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) using java language or [opencv andoid ndk](https://medium.com/@siantlords/opencv-and-android-ndk-integration-in-android-studio-883a810189e2) using c++ language. But before diving into image processing in opencv it is good to have good understanding of images and image processing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What will you say about Tensorflow?

Comment: TensorFlow is a generic neural network architecture. It could be trained to detect image features, but only with a large set of training data. It is good to compare them in your own requirements but i recommend using opencv for  android but If you really want to use tensorflow in android use transfer learning.